# Calling to c# function from javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010

I have a javascript function and c# fanction. I need to call to the c# function from the javascript function, but I don't know how...

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

The javascript function-

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        function DeleteBook(idimg) {
// idimg is a string
            var userConfirm = window.confirm('Are you sure?');

            if (userConfirm == true) {
                control.Sess(idimg);// The line which is colling to the c# function - doesn't work
                window.open('Delete.aspx');
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
    </script>
```

The c# function-

```
protected void Sess(string id)
    {
        Session["forDelete"] = id;
    }
```

Comment: You could expose the methods you want to call in a WCF service, and hit them via ajax.

Comment: I don't know how to do that...

Comment: Look at TYY's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a web method

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static Application GetApplication(int id)
{
}
```

and in javascript you then do something like this

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "Applications.aspx/GetApplication",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{'id':" + id + "}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: methodToDoSomethingOnSuccess,
            error: function (rhq, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert ("some went awry");

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create an input of type submit that invokes your C# function using the HTML and make it hidden. Then create a div tag and using javascript do this:

```
@CSS
.Hidden {
     display:none;
}

@HTML     
<input type="submit" id="SubmitTag" OnClick="C# Functin" class="Hidden" runat="server" />
//if using MVC and Razor 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action Name", "Controller Name", FormMethod.Post)) {
    <input type="submit" id="SubmitTag" class="Hidden" />
} 

<div id="OnDivClick"> what you want to do in here </div>

@JS
$('#OnDivClick').click(function () {
    $('#SubmitTag').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, your JS function invokes your C# method regardless of what you want to do, just use the JS function with your image button!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are ways to do this but I believe that you're trying to save something in the `Session` for the `Delete.aspx` page to read it. The simplest solution is just post the data in:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
form.setAttribute('action', 'Delete.aspx');
form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
form.innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" name="forDelete" value="' + idimg + '" />';
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

This dynamically creates a form and submits it with `idimg` which will open the page `Delete.aspx` in a new window.

All that's left to do is go to the `C#` part of `Delete.aspx` page and catch the incoming data:

```
string idimg = Request.Form["forDelete"];
// Do whatever with it
Session["forDelete"] = idimg; // If you still want to save it in Session
```